# Install Ubuntu 14.04 from bootable USB: Could not find kernel image: /isolinux/isolinux.cfg

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb, kernel

I wanted to install Ubuntu 14.04 from USB. At first I got the error

```
No default or UI configuration directive found
```

after reading through the forums a bit I renamed the isolinux folder as well as the .bin and .cfg files to syslinux. However, after I did that now the error

```
Could not find kernel image: /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
```

shows up.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create your bootable usb key under windows with LinuxLive USB Creator http://www.linuxliveusb.com/fr/home ?

If you are only on linux, try to Download you linux iso and follow this procedure

Type

```
fdisk -l
```

Find your usb key path (for exemple /dev/sdd here)

Flash your key with the iso. (It will erase everything without confirmation, please double check every parameters).

```
sudo dd if=path/to/your/iso/linux.iso of=/dev/sdd bs=4096
```

Please wait carefully the end of the process.
Now you got a bootable usb key with your iso.

Best regards